# Juno sources - no release file

Tags: updates, apt, release-juno, software-sources

I have just installed Juno but cannot update.

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for cipeos:        
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for cipeos:       
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu juno InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                              
Ign:4 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno InRelease                                   
Hit:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                             
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu juno InRelease                 
Hit:7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease    
Err:8 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno Release                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu juno Release                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu juno Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu juno Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu juno Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 3):

I fix this replacing `juno` for `bionic` on

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
```

to find this list of files you can use

```
sudo grep -R juno /etc/apt
```

Comment: I hope it works but I cannot confirm. I have meanwhile switched Linuxes in favor of Lubuntu 18.10-Lxqt. Until next time!

Comment: Can confirm the above works. Used `find /etc/apt -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 sed -i 's/juno/bionic/g'` to automate the process.

Comment: Thank You (Can confirm the above works. Used find /etc/apt -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 sed -i 's/juno/bionic/g' to automate the process. – sudosensei Jan 14 at 13:53)...
works for me fine