# Fresh Juno install can't update/install any packages

Tags: release-juno, apt

I've just completed a fresh install of 5.0 from the ISO on the website, but am unable to update/upgrade packages.

Trying to run `sudo apt update`, or install anything from the AppCentre both result in the following error:

`E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

This seems to be the same issue as in this page:
[Juno sources - no release file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16469/juno-sources-no-release-file)

I'm about to try following those instructions to resolve it, but thought I'd post an update that this is still an issue. Unable to install software on a fresh install seems like a rather critical bug to fix from a user experience point of view...

Answer (score 1):

After executing `sudo apt update` I see this line in terminal's output:

`http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease`

instead of

`http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter juno Release`

As my system doesn't have any issues with updates, you could try to swap the lines and see if it helps. (If it doesn't, just revert the process and try other solutions.)